# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE error in Crawler code

Tags: php

I have searched for this answer, but unable to find it.  I am getting the error message, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" and believe it to be related to the "a" listed on line 30.  Any ideas how to make this code right?

```
<?php
class Crawler {
    protected $markup = ”;
    public function __construct($uri) {
        $this->markup = $this->getMarkup($uri);
    }

    public function getMarkup($uri) {
        return file_get_contents($uri);
    }

    public function get($type) {
        $method = array($this,”_get_”.$type);
        if (method_exists($this,$method[1]))
            return call_user_func($method);
        return false;
    }

    protected function _get_images() {
        if (!empty($this->markup)){
            preg_match_all("/<img([^>]+)\/>/i", $this->markup, $images);
            return !empty($images[1]) ? $images[1] : FALSE;
        }
    }

    protected function _get_links() {
        if (!empty($this->markup)){
            preg_match_all("/<a([^>]+)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/i", $this->markup, $links);
            return !empty($links[1]) ? $links[1] : FALSE;
        }
    }
}
a 
$crawl = new Crawler("http://www.facebook.com");
$images = $crawl->get("images");
$links = $crawl->get("links");
?>
```

Comment: Would it kill to try removing the a?

Comment: it does kill it.  I then get an error that says "Use of undefined constant â€ - assumed 'â€' in..."

Comment: Sheeple please, questions [about syntax errors == too localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87149/should-syntax-error-questions-be-closed-as-too-localized-after-being-answered).

Comment: Those look an awful lot like curly quotes to me. They at least don't look right in my browser. In other words, `” != "`. And, you know, one `"` needs two `""` to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `a`, and use straight quotes `"` instead of your current curly quotes.

Comment: When I try that I get the error, "Use of undefined constant â€_get_â€ - assumed 'â€_get_â€' in..."

Comment: Again, you have curly quotes. Replace them with straight quotes.

Comment: feel like a dunce.  didn't pay attention to the curly quotes and straight quotes.  Thanks this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting a `;` after your `a` on line 30

Comment: Yes.  still get the same error as mentioned above "undefined constant a..."